# Why phpmailer is not sending mail to my domain mail server

Tags: php, phpmailer

> I'm trying to send mail to my domain mail server:
> I used a try{} catch(){} to detect if there is any error, but surprisingly, there isn't any error.

```
<?php 
function Redirect_to($New_Location){
    header("Location:" . $New_Location);
    exit;
}
if(isset($_POST['Submitenq'])){
    require('phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');

    define ('GUSER','courses@cadcentreju.org');
    define ('GPWD','mymailpass');

    $recever1 = 'courses@cadcentreju.org';

    $enq_name = $_POST["enq_name"];
    $enq_email = $_POST["enq_email"];
    $enq_phone = $_POST["enq_phone"];
    $enq_message = $_POST["enq_message"];

    date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
    $CurrentTime = time();
    $DateTime = strftime("%B-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S",$CurrentTime);
    
    if(empty($enq_name) || empty($enq_email) || empty($enq_phone) || empty($enq_message)){
        Redirect_to("index.php?error=1");
    }else{
        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        try{
            $mail->IsSMTP();
            $mail->Mailer = "smtp";
                // $mail->SMTPDebug  = 2; 
            $mail->SMTPAuth   = TRUE;
            $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
            $mail->Port       = 465;
            $mail->Host       = "mail.supremecluster.com";
            // $mail->CharSet   = "UTF-8";
            $mail->Username   = GUSER;
            $mail->Password   = GPWD;
            $mail->isHTML(true); 
                $mail->setFrom($enq_email,$enq_name);
                $mail->addAddress($recever1);
        
              $mail->Subject = 'Enquery Mail from - '. $enq_name;
              $mail->Body = '<table class="table" cellspacing="0">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="2">Enquery Mail from - '. $enq_name .'</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">'. '<p>Dear Sir / Madam, I have some enqueries as follows :</p></br>' .'</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Email:</td>
                    <td>'. $enq_email .'</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Phone No:</td>
                    <td>'. $enq_phone .'</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>City:</td>
                    <td>'. $sendercity .'</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Message:</td>
                    <td>'. $enq_message .'</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Date of Enquery:</td>
                    <td>'. $DateTime .'</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
              </table>';
              
              $mail->send();
              $success_msg =  "Your Message Sent Successfully: ";
        }catch(phpmailerException $e){
            echo $e->errorMessage();
        }catch(Exception $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }

    }

}

?>
<?php include 'header.php'; ?>

<div style="height:50vh;margin-top: 268px; background:#ddd;" class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <?php 
        if(isset($success_msg)){
    ?>
    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">

        <?php
            echo $success_msg . $enq_name;
        ?>
    </div>
    <?php
        }else{
    ?>
    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
<?php
    echo "Something went wrong";

?>
</div>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
</div>

<?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
```

> It's showing me that the email sent successfully, but I'm not getting
> any mail.

*I've contacted my server helpline, they're saying that certain IPs were blocked. But now I've allowed these IPs from the CPanel. But still, the mails are not sent*

**I really need help on this :)**

*Thanks for taking the time to read.*

Comment: provider sometimes block other locations. you must setup your gmail account to not block this

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Max. But I'm not trying to send mails to any gmail server. This my domain server.

Comment: if you want me to notice your reply you must add a @ in front of my  name here as i did now.

Comment: if you are trying to send email via the domain server, this is going to not work. You must definitively send email via the email server. And then you will have some log files who will tell you why emails are not sent. Please take a look in the logfiles

Comment: @MaxMuster Thanks for the reply. But I don't know how to do that using phpMailer.

Comment: You need the QMail or Postfix logs from `mail.supremecluster.com` - the error will be written there.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHPMailer doesn't throw exceptions by default – you have to ask for them by passing `true` to the constructor, as in `$mail = new PHPMailer(true);`. Without that you have to check the return values from methods like `send()` to find out if they worked.

Errors are stored in the `ErrorInfo` property – see [any of the code examples provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/tree/master/examples) to see how to handle errors correctly.

You can also set `$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;` to see what your mail server is saying. Beyond that, read [the PHPMailer troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting).

Answer (score 0):

My final Working Code is:

```
function Redirect_to($New_Location){
    header("Location:" . $New_Location);
    exit;
}
if(isset($_POST['Submitenq'])){
    require('phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');

    define ('GUSER','courses@cadcentreju.org');
    define ('GPWD','mailpass');

    $recever1 = 'courses@cadcentreju.org';

    $enq_name = $_POST["enq_name"];
    $enq_email = $_POST["enq_email"];
    $enq_phone = $_POST["enq_phone"];
    $enq_message = $_POST["enq_message"];

    date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
    $CurrentTime = time();
    $DateTime = strftime("%B-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S",$CurrentTime);
    
    if(empty($enq_name) || empty($enq_email) || empty($enq_phone) || empty($enq_message)){
        Redirect_to("index.php?error=1");
    }else{
        $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
        try{
            $mail->IsSMTP();
            $mail->Mailer = "smtp";
                // $mail->SMTPDebug  = 2; 
            $mail->SMTPAuth   = TRUE;
            $mail->SMTPSecure = "none";
            $mail->Port       = 25;
            $mail->Host       = "mail.supremecluster.com";
            // $mail->CharSet   = "UTF-8";
            $mail->Username   = GUSER;
            $mail->Password   = GPWD;
            $mail->isHTML(true); 
            $mail->setFrom($enq_email,$enq_name);
            $mail->From = GUSER; 
            $mail->FromName = $enq_name;

            $mail->addAddress($recever1);
        
              $mail->Subject = 'Enquiry Mail from - '. $enq_name;
              $mail->Body = '<table class="table" cellspacing="0">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="2">Enquiry Mail from - '. $enq_name .'</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">'. '<p>Dear Sir / Madam, I have some enquiries. My Details are as follows :</p></br>' .'</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Email:</td>
                    <td>'. $enq_email .'</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Phone No:</td>
                    <td>'. $enq_phone .'</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Message:</td>
                    <td>'. $enq_message .'</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Date and TIME of Enquery:</td>
                    <td>'. $DateTime .'</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
              </table>';
              
              $mail->send();
              $success_msg =  "Your Message Sent Successfully: ";
        }catch(phpmailerException $e){
            echo $e->errorMessage();
        }catch(Exception $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
```

I decided to send mail from my own server instead of Gmail server:

So I changed:

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
```

to

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = "none";
```

Most Important thing to remember that:

```
$mail->Username   = GUSER;
```

And

```
$mail->From = GUSER;
```

**MUST BE SAME**

AND

Also,
We have to pass true to the constructor:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true)
```

> // Argument true in constructor enables exceptions

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Gmail Account -> Security

Find "Access less secure app". Turn it ON and Run your PHP file again.

The Mail should be sent.